# how to solve EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios5.1, xcode4.4

I'm new to iOS,, I got an  `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception in following line

`nextscrn.fullTextValue=self.fulltextFromSecond;`

This nextscrn object has created in this way above to that line.

`ImageVisible *nextscrn=[[ImageVisible alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];`

Can any one explain me what is the reason for this and how can I solve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `nextscrn.fullTextValue=self.fulltextFromSecond;` is the line where you're getting the exception then almost certainly one of `nextscrn` or.`self` is set to an invalid pointer.

First step is to establish which one it is, then find out why it got that way.

One way to establish which is the problem is with debugging tools (probably the best way). If that's not possible, you can try something like:

```
void *xyzzy = self.fulltextFromSecond;
```

and see if that crashes (I've used `void *` because I don't know what type your `self` is, but you should probably substitute the "real" type).

If that crashes, it's the `self` that's corrupted but I'd consider this possibility the least likely. If not, try a similar method for `nextscrn.fullTextValue`.

Comment: in nextscrn's fullTextValue I have defined as nonatomic,retain in self.fulltextFromSecond is also nonatomic,retain. both are synthesized and released in dealloc method. what would be the reason for this

Comment: @saj, first check their values to see if they're sane. And be aware that it's not only intentional writing to variables that can cause incorrect values. Memory corruption can occur for a great many unexpected reasons, such as buffer overflows. First step (as I said), find out which one is the problem.